# Client Certificate and NSURLSession

Tags: ios, ssl

Okay, I am new to the wide wonders of SSL certificates and authentication so I am probably doing something very very obviously wrong here. But I am trying to setup an NSURLSession to download a file from server proxied through an SSL Gateway. For reasons involved with the solution we are building we want to use a non-standard CA for signing the cert. As a result I have a CACert, server certificate and a server private key. These have been worked into a pkcs12 file which I load to get the identity from the file and I then try to do a security trust evaluation with that cert.

What I get is that if I connect to a server that uses a publicly signed cert then the server trust authentication works just fine and I get the callbacks I am expecting. So I know I've done the delegate hookup correctly.

However with the client certificate challenge on the test URL indicated in the code I get a -9802 error. Which suggests that either the cert is being evaluated properly or I have got something else wrong. Indeed the server tries to move on to ServerTrust and then curls everything up. (But curiously the didBecomeInvalidWithError callback doesn't get called, which I was expecting when everything goes wrong.)

I have turned CFNetworking diagnostics on and the device log ends up looking like this :-

```
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:2] 15:38:38.524 {  
  AddCookies Continue: request GET https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001 HTTP/1.1  
        HTTPProtocol: Task: 14dcc7c0  
  } [3:2]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:3] 15:38:38.526 {  
  Protocol Enqueue: request GET https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001 HTTP/1.1  
          Request: <CFURLRequest 0x14f48f60 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
          Message: GET https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001 HTTP/1.1  
          Sending: dict [4] {  
                       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
                       Accept-Language: en-us  
                                Accept: */  
                   }  
  } [3:3]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:4] 15:38:38.533 {  
  SocketStream IO Logging  
  } [3:4]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:5] 15:38:38.544 {  
  TCP Connection Created  
  conn: 0x14f53d10 for name 103.20.137.69, port 444  
  } [3:5]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:6] 15:38:38.548 {  
  TCP Connection Start  
  conn: 0x14f53d10  
  } [3:6]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:7] 15:38:38.610 {  
  SocketStream TCP Connection Complete  
  conn: 0x14f53d10  
    fd: 7  
  error: 0  
  } [3:7]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:8] 15:38:38.613 {  
  { fd: 7, local 10.47.29.209:53929 => peer 103.20.137.69:444 } RAW-SENT 201  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > data [ 201 ] bytes {  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000000: 1603 0300 c401 0000 c003 0358 1168 ae99    ...........X.h..  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000010: 94f9 5ed2 d848 bb05 c846 5654 71c9 e3c9    ..^..H...FVTq...  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000020: cd65 210b a324 dacc 75e2 a900 0018 00ff    .e!..$..u.......  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000030: c02c c02b c024 c00a c023 c009 c030 c02f    .,.+.$.-.#...0./  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000040: c028 c027 c013 0100 007f 0000 0012 0010    .(.'............  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000050: 0000 0d31 3033 2e32 302e 3133 372e 3639    ..-103.20.137.69  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000060: 000a 0008 0006 0017 0018 0019 000b 0002    .-..............  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000070: 0100 000d 000e 000c 0501 0401 0201 0503    ...-............  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000080: 0403 0203 3374 0000 0010 0030 002e 0268    ....3t.....0...h  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 00000090: 3205 6832 2d31 3605 6832 2d31 3505 6832    2.h2-16.h2-15.h2  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 000000a0: 2d31 3408 7370 6479 2f33 2e31 0673 7064    -14.spdy/3.1.spd  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 000000b0: 792f 3308 6874 7470 2f31 2e31 0005 0005    y/3.http/1.1....  
  RAW-SENT (7) | > 000000c0: 0100 0000 0000 1200 00                     .........        
  RAW-SENT (7) | > }  
  } [3:8]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:9] 15:38:38.617 {  
  ioLogger  
  logStruct: array [4] {  
                BEGIN SSL RECORD DECODE: SENT  
                decodeHandshake [0] @ 0x14f5d915, version 303, length 196 (0xc4)  
                ClientHello (1, 0x1), length 192 (0xc0)  
                END SSL RECORD DECODE: SENT  
            }  
  } [3:9]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:10] 15:38:38.718 {  
  { fd: 7, local 10.47.29.209:53929 => peer 103.20.137.69:444 } RAW-READ 1368  
  RAW-READ (7) | < data [ 1368 ] bytes {  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000000: 1603 0305 a002 0000 4d03 0358 1168 b65d    ........M..X.h.]  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000010: 4b61 2b40 e5f7 65d5 bbea a3d1 ce5d 113f    Ka+@..e......].?  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000020: 86be 2d04 9288 fd34 2a86 d620 5811 68b6    ..-....4*.. X.h.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000030: 51f5 0beb 192f 0954 9556 c1f8 6d18 1f4b    Q..../.T.V..m..K  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000040: 5304 638c a110 b2f6 09ab cff2 c030 0000    S.c..........0..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000050: 05ff 0100 0100 0b00 042b 0004 2800 0242    .........+..(..B  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000060: 3082 023e 3082 01a7 a003 0201 0202 0821    0..>0..........!  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000070: 92e4 4931 8b9b ad30 0d06 092a 8648 86f7    ..I1...0-..*.H..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000080: 0d01 0105 0500 3025 3123 3021 0603 5504    -.....0%1#0!..U.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000090: 030c 1a66 692d 706f 696e 7379 732d 7372    ...fi-poinsys-sr  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000000a0: 762d 7465 7374 2d30 3031 2d63 6130 2017    v-test-001-ca0 .  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000000b0: 0d30 3830 3332 3631 3335 3035 305a 180f    -080326135050Z..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000000c0: 3230 3538 3033 3236 3133 3530 3530 5a30    20580326135050Z0  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000000d0: 2d31 2b30 2906 0355 0403 0c22 6669 2d70    -1+0)..U..."fi-p  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000000e0: 6f69 6e73 7973 2d73 7276 2d74 6573 7467    oinsys-srv-testg  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000000f0: 7731 2d30 3031 2d67 656e 6572 616c 3081    w1-001-general0.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000100: 9f30 0d06 092a 8648 86f7 0d01 0101 0500    .0-..*.H..-.....  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000110: 0381 8d00 3081 8902 8181 00b4 1d0e 5f53    ....0........._S  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000120: 9179 2d45 80d2 4746 2164 1cac 8613 3e67    .y-E..GF!d....>g  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000130: 628c 2514 0036 e770 ca16 15ed 73da 5997    b.%..6.p....s.Y.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000140: 2c10 5c5f ce84 4225 5857 20a5 04af 2879    ,.\_..B%XW ...(y  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000150: 661a b7c5 a9db b05c dd47 a996 63ed 58e6    f......\.G..c.X.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000160: 4d7a 34f4 e4b7 26fb 87c8 a08b 48e9 b504    Mz4...&.....H...  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000170: 4e01 9aa9 aea4 fb02 93b6 0816 0a9b 1054    N...........-..T  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000180: 6d7b 2647 dd66 ade5 e0f4 79f1 3b01 7bbf    m{&G.f....y.;.{.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000190: 044a 6954 6be1 408a ce75 8302 0301 0001    .JiTk.@..u......  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000001a0: a36d 306b 3009 0603 551d 1304 0230 0030    .m0k0...U....0.0  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000001b0: 5e06 0355 1d1f 0457 3055 3053 a051 a04f    ^..U...W0U0S.Q.O  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000001c0: 864d 6874 7470 733a 2f2f 706f 696e 7473    .Mhttps://points  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000001d0: 736c 7465 7374 3a38 3434 332f 6b6d 732f    sltest:8443/kms/  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000001e0: 6372 6c2f 6765 7463 726c 2e68 746d 6c3f    crl/getcrl.html?  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000001f0: 6e61 6d65 3d66 692d 706f 696e 7379 732d    name=fi-poinsys-  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000200: 7372 762d 7465 7374 2d30 3031 2d63 6130    srv-test-001-ca0  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000210: 0d06 092a 8648 86f7 0d01 0105 0500 0381    -..*.H..-.......  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000220: 8100 13f7 5f61 4699 d11c 1199 87d6 964a    ...._aF........J  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000230: 7e37 4454 94e6 3f8c 063f c560 68f3 4f89    ~7DT..?..?.`h.O.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000240: 9f53 1521 5cf3 aa47 f57c 007a e54b 1b47    .S.!\..G.|.z.K.G  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000250: 8c98 eaaa 235b 3fcf 819a 3df9 5540 a67b    ....#[?...=.U@.{  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000260: 02f1 013a c2c7 a523 a679 438f 58b3 af01    ...:...#.yC.X...  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000270: 8a9e f3fb de96 ac7e 2d38 4216 a794 502e    .......~-8B...P.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000280: 1b7d 9ad5 cf3b 1ebe 745e c976 bb03 90f0    .}...;..t^.v....  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000290: f8a7 4b81 5319 197f 221d 0d5f 504b c69a    ..K.S...".-_PK..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000002a0: 10aa 0001 e030 8201 dc30 8201 45a0 0302    .....0...0..E...  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000002b0: 0102 0208 6c89 815a 8bf7 15f5 300d 0609    ....l..Z....0-..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000002c0: 2a86 4886 f70d 0101 0505 0030 2531 2330    *.H..-.....0%1#0  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000002d0: 2106 0355 0403 0c1a 6669 2d70 6f69 6e73    !..U....fi-poins  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000002e0: 7973 2d73 7276 2d74 6573 742d 3030 312d    ys-srv-test-001-  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000002f0: 6361 3020 170d 3038 3033 3236 3133 3530    ca0 .-0803261350  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000300: 3530 5a18 0f32 3035 3830 3332 3631 3335    50Z..20580326135  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000310: 3035 305a 3025 3123 3021 0603 5504 030c    050Z0%1#0!..U...  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000320: 1a66 692d 706f 696e 7379 732d 7372 762d    .fi-poinsys-srv-  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000330: 7465 7374 2d30 3031 2d63 6130 819f 300d    test-001-ca0..0-  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000340: 0609 2a86 4886 f70d 0101 0105 0003 818d    ..*.H..-........  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000350: 0030 8189 0281 8100 859a a533 e990 210b    .0.........3..!.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000360: 58c1 8b58 984a fd75 337c c021 d374 02d8    X..X.J.u3|.!.t..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000370: f640 ff05 3efd a51a 9df7 f6eb 1023 52bc    .@..>........#R.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000380: ac59 a650 e4ad 9d1f 02e6 97db c914 a01b    .Y.P............  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000390: cd30 4945 8d71 5178 44f8 b4d4 9cba 2b8a    .0IE.qQxD.....+.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000003a0: 9077 1d85 9547 9c49 a043 7879 6899 2048    .w...G.I.Cxyh. H  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000003b0: 6fa5 d537 0010 0591 9d61 e854 5613 3d1d    o..7.....a.TV.=.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000003c0: 4677 5f8a ddb8 8d4d a885 3984 1cd9 7550    Fw_....M..9...uP  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000003d0: 96f4 acef 2a9f 7633 0203 0100 01a3 1330    ....*.v3.......0  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000003e0: 1130 0f06 0355 1d13 0408 3006 0101 ff02    .0...U....0.....  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000003f0: 0101 300d 0609 2a86 4886 f70d 0101 0505    ..0-..*.H..-....  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000400: 0003 8181 007b a0cd 116b a28f b536 67bf    .....{...k...6g.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000410: f87e 7b61 7543 411a 6047 7ca9 e54a 1a36    .~{auCA.`G|..J.6  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000420: e688 cd15 e346 e519 3f46 f900 79a8 e027    .....F..?F..y..'  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000430: 43f9 b963 a0f6 81d0 26c5 f66d 9d88 017d    C..c....&..m...}  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000440: 7c99 3168 2cf4 dced 64f8 5624 81d2 6dd2    |.1h,...d.V$..m.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000450: aaf4 0a0f c21d e196 e557 196c 0686 d698    ..-......W.l....  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000460: 5f6a 2d12 996c 3157 0ba7 ee35 498c db3a    _j-..l1W...5I..:  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000470: 2835 34cb b6e5 b941 7fac bf9f cfaa 5b98    (54....A......[.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000480: d118 ca76 360c 0000 c903 0017 4104 bf45    ...v6.......A..E  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000490: 344f 7916 08d2 fa31 ec81 ac4e 7baf bfe1    4Oy....1...N{...  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000004a0: e04e 459d 2043 f3f9 8208 fce6 35ef bc99    .NE. C......5...  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000004b0: b606 a4f7 19eb 3c16 7131 ade6 4952 1dc5    ......<.q1..IR..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000004c0: 3b21 3cde ab1d c06f 870e 6580 9489 0501    ;!<....o..e.....  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000004d0: 0080 9468 d320 2901 bcb4 07b9 691c c9b2    ...h. ).....i...  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000004e0: feae 734a dbb5 a658 a03f 93cb c769 2588    ..sJ...X.?...i%.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 000004f0: 5e5d 011c 89bb dc6e 7d72 054e b173 c8f5    ^].....n}r.N.s..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000500: 90c1 c0db d0ee a59d c69e 8a0f 0195 3d7b    ..............={  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000510: c4f1 b067 5cb8 131c a79d ad43 0bc9 1cbd    ...g\......C....  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000520: c8f0 4f57 9fbb 4680 3afa 182f af23 bea9    ..OW..F.:../.#..  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000530: 03dd c86d eb5a fae3 c449 a0b2 688e 4b0a    ...m.Z...I..h.K-  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000540: 2188 f37b a27e 5fa2 4221 d52c a98b 7e90    !..{.~_.B!.,..~.  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000550: 5d81 0d00 004b 0301                        ].-..K..         
  RAW-READ (7) | < }  
  } [3:10]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:11] 15:38:38.730 {  
  { fd: 7, local 10.47.29.209:53929 => peer 103.20.137.69:444 } RAW-READ 77  
  RAW-READ (7) | < data [ 77 ] bytes {  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000000: 0240 0016 0603 0601 0503 0501 0403 0401    .@..............  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000010: 0303 0301 0203 0201 0202 002d 002b 3029    ...........-.+0)  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000020: 3127 3025 0603 5504 030c 1e66 692d 706f    1'0%..U....fi-po  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000030: 696e 7379 732d 7465 7374 636c 742d 636d    insys-testclt-cm  
  RAW-READ (7) | < 00000040: 7331 2d30 3031 2d63 610e 0000 00           s1-001-ca....    
  RAW-READ (7) | < }  
  } [3:11]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:12] 15:38:38.732 {  
  ioLogger  
  logStruct: array [12] {  
                BEGIN SSL RECORD DECODE: READ  
                decodeHandshake [0] @ 0x15c62025, version 303, length 1440 (0x5a0)  
                ServerHello (2, 0x2), length 77 (0x4d)  
                decodeHandshake [1] @ 0x15c62076, version 303, length 1440 (0x5a0)  
                Certificate (11, 0xb), length 1067 (0x42b)  
                decodeHandshake [2] @ 0x15c624a5, version 303, length 1440 (0x5a0)  
                ServerKeyExchange (12, 0xc), length 201 (0xc9)  
                decodeHandshake [3] @ 0x15c62572, version 303, length 1440 (0x5a0)  
                CertificateRequest (13, 0xd), length 75 (0x4b)  
                decodeHandshake [4] @ 0x15c625c1, version 303, length 1440 (0x5a0)  
                ServerHelloDone (14, 0xe), length 0 (0x0)  
                END SSL RECORD DECODE: READ  
            }  
  } [3:12]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:13] 15:38:38.739 {  
  Client Cert Requested  
  Distinguished Names: 1  
                   0: << DATA <CFData 0x14def8c0 [0x38002170]>{length = 43, capacity = 43, bytes = 0x30293127302506035504030c1e66692d ... 312d3030312d6361} >>  
  } [3:13]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:14] 15:38:38.742 {  
  Authentication Challenge  
    Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x14dcb620 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
  Challenge: challenge space https://103.20.137.69:444/, ClientCertificateRequested (Hash c3626e29)  
  } [3:14]  
Oct 27 15:38:38 Philip-Banks-ipod Unknown[791] <Error>:  
Oct 27 15:38:43 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]  
Oct 27 15:38:44 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Warning>: Certificates found: 1  
Oct 27 15:38:44 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]  
Oct 27 15:38:44 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Warning>: User: (null), certificates (  
     "<cert(0x160214f0) s: 400-133-738-MOB i: fi-poinsys-testclt-cms1-001-ca>"  
  ) identity:<SecIdentityRef: 0x16020270>  
Oct 27 15:38:46 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:15] 15:38:46.070 {  
  Use Credential  
     Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x14dcb620 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
  Credential: Name: 400-133-738-MOB, Persistence: permanent  
  } [3:15]  
Oct 27 15:38:46 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:16] 15:38:46.074 {  
  touchConnection  
           Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x14dcb620 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
  Timeout Interval: 60.000 seconds  
  } [3:16]  
Oct 27 15:38:46 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:17] 15:38:46.078 {  
  Peer certificate  
  Subject Sum: fi-poinsys-srv-testgw1-001-general  
     Summary: fi-poinsys-srv-test-001-ca  
  } [3:17]  
Oct 27 15:38:46 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:18] 15:38:46.093 {  
  Authentication Challenge  
    Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x14dcb620 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
  Challenge: challenge space https://103.20.137.69:444/, ServerTrustEvaluationRequested (Hash c3626e29)  
  } [3:18]  
Oct 27 15:38:47 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:19] 15:38:47.250 {  
  Use Credential  
     Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x14dcb620 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
  Credential: null  
  } [3:19]  
Oct 27 15:38:47 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:20] 15:38:47.252 {  
  touchConnection  
           Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x14dcb620 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
  Timeout Interval: 60.000 seconds  
  } [3:20]  
Oct 27 15:38:47 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf SSLHostname] [root AnchorTrusted]  
Oct 27 15:38:47 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Warning>: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)  
Oct 27 15:38:47 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:21] 15:38:47.255 {  
  Response Error  
  Request: <CFURLRequest 0x14f48f60 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
   Error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=2, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x14f76660>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x160274c0 [0x38002170]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (  
          0 : <cert(0x14f70280) s: fi-poinsys-srv-testgw1-001-general i: fi-poinsys-srv-test-001-ca>  
          1 : <cert(0x14f70520) s: fi-poinsys-srv-test-001-ca i: fi-poinsys-srv-test-001-ca>  
          )}, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificates=<CFArray 0x14f74740 [0x38002170]>{type = mutable-small, count = 2, values = (  
          0 : <SecIdentityRef: 0x16020270>  
          1 : <cert(0x160214f0) s: 400-133-738-MOB i: fi-poinsys-testclt-cms1-001-ca>  
          )}}  
  } [3:21]  
Oct 27 15:38:47 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:22] 15:38:47.258 {  
            Did Fail  
              Loader: <CFURLRequest 0x14dcb620 [0x38002170]> {url = https://103.20.137.69:444/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001, cs = 0x0}  
               Error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=2, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x14f76660>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x160274c0 [0x38002170]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (  
                      0 : <cert(0x14f70280) s: fi-poinsys-srv-testgw1-001-general i: fi-poinsys-srv-test-001-ca>  
                      1 : <cert(0x14f70520) s: fi-poinsys-srv-test-001-ca i: fi-poinsys-srv-test-001-ca>  
                      )}, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificates=<CFArray 0x14f74740 [0x38002170]>{type = mutable-small, count = 2, values = (  
                      0 : <SecIdentityRef: 0x16020270>  
                      1 : <cert(0x160214f0) s: 400-133-738-MOB i: fi-poinsys-testclt-cms1-001-ca>  
                      )}}  
  init to origin load: 0.011323s  
          total time: 8.75724s  
         total bytes: 0  
  } [3:22]  
Oct 27 15:38:47 Philip-Banks-ipod MPEtestApplication[793] <Notice>: CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:23] 15:38:47.275 {  
  ~HTTPProtocol: nullptr request  
       Request: null  
          sent: 0  
      received: 0  
     cell sent: 0  
  cell received: 0  
  } [3:23]
```

Which seems to be pretty clear that the authentication failed, but not why it failed at. I'd appreciate any useful suggestions here as I am kinda stuck at this point.

This code is being build using XCode 8 building against the 10 SDK and deploying it onto an iOS 9.3.5 device.

Here is the code in question :-

```
#import "testSSLClass.h"  
@interface testSSLClass()<NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate> {  
  NSString* mDownloadURL;  
  NSURLSessionConfiguration* mDownloadConfiguration;  
  NSURLSession* mDownloadSession;  
  NSURLSessionDataTask* mDownloadTask;  
  NSMutableData* mDataReceived;  
}  
@end  
@implementation testSSLClass  
-(instancetype)init  
{  
  if (self = [super init])  
  {  
    mDownloadURL = @"https://103.20.137.69:443/downloadfile.aspx?filename=MON___00DADDF5FFFF00&tspid=100581332001";  
    mDownloadConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];  
  }  
  return self;  
}  
-(void)doADownload  
{  
  mDataReceived = [NSMutableData new];  
  NSURL* URLtoFetch = [NSURL URLWithString:mDownloadURL];  
  mDownloadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:mDownloadConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];  
  mDownloadTask = [mDownloadSession dataTaskWithURL:URLtoFetch];  
  [mDownloadTask resume];  
}  
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler  
{  
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]) {  
    [self willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge completionHandler:completionHandler];  
  } else {  
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);  
  }  
}  
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  
{  
  [mDataReceived appendData:data];  
}  
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)proposedResponse completionHandler:(void (^)(NSCachedURLResponse * _Nullable))completionHandler  
{  
  [mDataReceived length];  
}  
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didBecomeInvalidWithError:(NSError *)error  
{  
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);  
}  
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didBecomeStreamTask:(NSURLSessionStreamTask *)streamTask  
{  
  NSLog(@"Did Become Stream Task");  
}  

- (void)willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler  
{  
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate])  
  {  
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString* directoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSString* cacertPath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"client.p12"];  
    NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cacertPath];  

    CFDataRef inP12data = (__bridge CFDataRef)p12data;  

    SecIdentityRef myIdentity;  
    SecTrustRef myTrust;  
    extractIdentityAndTrust(inP12data, &myIdentity, &myTrust);  
    assert(myIdentity != nil);  
    assert(myTrust != nil);  

    long count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(myTrust);  
    NSMutableArray* myCertificates = nil;  
    if(count > 0) {  
      myCertificates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];  
      for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {  
        [myCertificates addObject:(__bridge id)SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(myTrust, i)];  
      }  
    }  

    SecTrustResultType trustResult;  
    OSStatus evalResult = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);  

    if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure)  
    {  
      CFDataRef errDataRef = SecTrustCopyExceptions(myTrust);  
      SecTrustSetExceptions(myTrust, errDataRef);  

      evalResult = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);  
    }  
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:myIdentity certificates:myCertificates persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];  
    assert(credential != nil);  

    NSLog(@"User: %@, certificates %@ identity:%@", [credential user], [credential certificates], [credential identity]);  
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];  
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);  
  } else {  
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);  
  }  
}  
OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inP12data, SecIdentityRef *identity, SecTrustRef *trust)  
{  
  OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;  

  CFStringRef password = CFSTR("password");  
  const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };  
  const void *values[] = { password };  

  CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);  

  CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);  
  securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12data, options, &items);  

  if (securityError == 0) {  
    CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);  
    const void *tempIdentity = NULL;  
    tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);  
    *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;  
    const void *tempTrust = NULL;  
    tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);  
    *trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;  

    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(items);  
    NSLog(@"Certificates found: %ld",count);  
  }  

  if (options) {  
    CFRelease(options);  
  }  

  return securityError;  
}  
@end
```

Any suggestions, tips or advice gratefully accepted.

Philip

Comment: This article might help you out https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning

Comment: Thanks, I have read that. But that seems to be certificate pinning for the ServerTrust authentication. Whereas I am trying to do ClientCertificate - I think.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, after some back and forth with a helpful Apple employee and banging a few heads locally to do certs in a sensible way this is the solution I ended up with :-

```
#import "testSSLClass.h"

@interface testSSLClass()<NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate> {
  NSString* mDownloadURL;
  NSURLSessionConfiguration* mDownloadConfiguration;
  NSURLSession* mDownloadSession;
  NSURLSessionDataTask* mDownloadTask;
  NSMutableData* mDataReceived;
}


@end

@implementation testSSLClass

-(instancetype)init
{
  if (self = [super init])
  {
    mDownloadURL = @"https://your.server.url";
    mDownloadConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)doADownload
{
  mDataReceived = [NSMutableData new];
  NSURL* URLtoFetch = [NSURL URLWithString:mDownloadURL];
  mDownloadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:mDownloadConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
  mDownloadTask = [mDownloadSession dataTaskWithURL:URLtoFetch];
  [mDownloadTask resume];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler
{
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]) {
    [self willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge completionHandler:completionHandler];
  } else {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
  }
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  NSLog(@"Appending data: %lu bytes", (unsigned long)[data length]);
  [mDataReceived appendData:data];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)proposedResponse completionHandler:(void (^)(NSCachedURLResponse * _Nullable))completionHandler
{
  // We got the data.
  NSLog(@"Download finished: %lu bytes", (unsigned long)[mDataReceived length]);
  completionHandler(NULL);
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didBecomeInvalidWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didBecomeStreamTask:(NSURLSessionStreamTask *)streamTask
{
  NSLog(@"Did Become Stream Task");
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"Download finished: %lu bytes", (unsigned long)[mDataReceived length]);
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);
  }
}

#pragma NSURLConnection delegate

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);
}

- (void)willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler
{
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate])
  {
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* directoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* cacertPath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/client.p12"];

    NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cacertPath];

    CFDataRef inP12data = (__bridge CFDataRef)p12data;

    SecIdentityRef myIdentity = nil;
    extractIdentity(inP12data, &myIdentity);
    assert(myIdentity != nil);

    NSURLCredential* credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:myIdentity certificates:nil persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    assert(credential != nil);

    NSLog(@"User: %@, certificates %@ identity:%@", [credential user], [credential certificates], [credential identity]);
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
  } else {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
  }
}

OSStatus extractIdentity(CFDataRef inP12data, SecIdentityRef *identity)
{
  OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

  CFStringRef password = CFSTR("password");
  const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
  const void *values[] = { password };

  CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

  CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
  securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12data, options, &items);

  if (securityError == errSecSuccess) {
    CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
    tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
    *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;

    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(items);
    NSLog(@"Certificates found: %ld",count);
  }

  if (options) {
    CFRelease(options);
  }

  return securityError;
}

@end
```

We use a locally downloaded pkcs12 format file which has the private key and the cert to establish an indentity. The cert is now being signed by a public CA which means iOS is all happy and things now work nicely. Hopefully this is useful for someone else banging their head a bit.

Comment: I am in your old situation, it seems that the only thing I have left to test is that the certificate is signed by a public CA , I hope it works

Comment: It should, the solution I outlined has been working nicely for us now.

Comment: I don't suppose you've done this in Swift too? I need to do the exact same thing, but only starting mobile development and feel so clueless looking around on the web

Comment: Sorry, no. We are still mostly objective-C with the projects I am working on. Haven't had the need yet to convert this to Swift.

Comment: helped me understanding the concept... thank you @PhilipBanks

Comment: Glad you found it useful Krishna and thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @PhilipBanks, Hi, i wonder if the certificate authentication comes from the server and not, as you show here, from the client side. Perhaps do you know how to send your certificate as a client to the server as part of the SSL session ? thanks !